# Session expiry implementation issues

Tags: jsp, session, session-cookies

I am trying to implement session expiry in my application. I follow MVC pattern. I set timeout in web.xml file.
This is my session expiry implementation

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)    throws    ServletException, IOException 
{
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null)
{
// controller code
}
else
response.sendRedirect("JSP/HomePage.jsp?message=Your Session Has Expired");     
}
```

AFAIK, request.getSession(false) will return a null object if requested session is not the one created already.

The above code works well when (i.e it redirects to HomePage.jsp) :
1.I make some form submit in any jsp page(after session has expired)
2.I refresh some page(after session has expired)

Now my problem is,(after session get expired) when I click on anchor tag link in one jsp page, it navigates to some new jsp page, there I make some form request, the code will not get transferred to the **HomePage.jsp**.

With the help of **HttpListener**, I am able to see that a new session is created and request.getSession(false) returns newly created session when  new jsp page get navigated(but in the first two cases, request.getSession(false) returns null).

Can anyone let me know what I am doing is OK? and In what way I should proceed now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the following line to your jsp file:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

it will instruct the servlet container **not** to create a session when the jsp is served.

Comment: It works exactly. Thank u. I wanna know what I am doing is correct? Shall I proceed in the same sense?

Comment: instead of checking if session is present, i would place a object in session and check if it is there. this way you do not need to care about where your session was created. if a session was created in a jsp i would redirect to the entry point of my application (f.e. login screen)

Comment: ... but in the end it depends on your requirements.